# Is it a good idea to nest constants in Redux?

Tags: redux, ngrx

In our Product we use Angular 6 together with NgRX 6. Instead of [defining our constants as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965856/what-is-the-point-of-the-constants-in-redux) `export const` strings, we use an object to encapsulate them:

```
export const ACTION_CONSTANTS = {
    'OPEN_MODAL'                              : 'OPEN_MODAL',
    'CLOSE_MODAL'                             : 'CLOSE_MODAL',
    'OPEN_TOOLTIP'                            : 'OPEN_TOOLTIP',
    'CLOSE_TOOLTIP'                           : 'CLOSE_TOOLTIP',
    ...
};
```

As the `ACTION_CONSTANTS` object gets bigger and prefixes get longer (`'DROPDOWN_ACTION_SKIP_SET_INIT_STATE'`), I would prefer to nest constants e.g. by feature:

```
export const ACTION_CONSTANTS = {
    'MODAL' : {
        'OPEN'                                : 'MODAL.OPEN',
        'CLOSE'                               : 'MODAL.CLOSE'
    },
    'TOOLTIP' : {
        'OPEN'                                : 'TOOLTIP.OPEN',
        'CLOSE'                               : 'TOOLTIP.CLOSE'
    },
    ...
};
```

**Is it a good idea or are there any downsides?** I could not find anything on formatting constants on the [Redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a bad idea, as long as you're able to keep it all organized. But I would suggest grouping your actions into different files. I find this the best way to keep things organized.

```
--ActionsFile   
  -modalActions.js   
  -toolTipAction.js
```

Comment: Imho a downside of this is that action constants could be equal in a large project without noticing (as they are just strings) and activate 2 reducers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep actions in different files, roughly aligned with models & reducers. And i have a naming convention like:

`ACTION_MODEL_OUTCOME`

So, for example, to load model of type `ProductGroup` i would have actions:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
LOAD_PRODUCTGROUP: enforceUnique("[ProductGroup] Laod ProductGroup"),
LOAD_PRODUCTGROUP_SUCCESS: enforceUnique("[ProductGroup] Load ProductGroup Success")
LOAD_PRODUCTGROUP_FAILURE: enforceUnique("[ProductGroup] Load ProductGroup Failure")
}
```

`enforceUnique` is a function that caches all registered actions and make sure there are no duplicates across the whole app.

Now, when you import actions for certain model, you import only those from file you need (e.g. `import ProductGroupActionTypes from 'actions/ProductGroupActions') and use them like  ProductGroupActionTypes.LOAD_PRODUCTGROUP`.

Usually, first one (without outcome suffix) is the one to initiate action and set some `pending` flag in reducer to show loader and also to initiate http calls in `@Effects`.

Second one, with `success` suffix is handled in reducer to change state.

Third one is error handling, whatever way you want to do it.